# Simple join takes far too long to run due to query plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, sql-execution-plan

Some context: I have two tables, smalltable and bigtable. Smalltable contains 10,000 rows, whereas bigtable contains 2,000,000, and I am using SQL Server 2008. I started with a query as follows:

```
select * from [dbo].[smalltable]  t1 
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[bigtable] t2 
on (t1.name1=t2.firstname and t1.name6=t2.lastname) or (t1.name6=t2.firstname and t1.name1=t2.lastname)
```

This query was running for over 15 minutes before I killed it - on inspecting the query plan, it was using a nested loop to do the inner join.

I then rewrote the query as follows:

```
select * from [dbo].[smalltable]  t1 
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[bigtable] t2 
on (t1.name1=t2.firstname and t1.name6=t2.lastname)
UNION
select * from [dbo].[smalltable]  t1 
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[bigtable] t2 
on (t1.name6=t2.firstname and t1.name1=t2.lastname)
```

The two queries above then instead executed using a Hash Match, and the whole query ran in 4 seconds.

My question is, why does SQL Server get the query plan so wrong, and was there anyway that I could have fixed the original query without rewriting it? I tried adding a hint to use a Hash Match to the first query, but it seems that you are not allowed to with multiple join criteria?

Update: Added examples of the kind of data in the tables as requested. Note, the code is looking for name matches where names may have been swapped around:

Smalltable(Columns name1,name6)

```
John, Smith
Johnny, Smith
Smythe, Jon
Michaels, Robert
Bob, Brown
```

Bigtable (Columns firstname,lastname)

```
John, Smith
John, Smythe
Johnny, Smith
Alison, Roberts
Robert, Michaels
Janet, Green
```

Comment: Please provide with sample table with data

Comment: See here about comparing estimated and actual query plans: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/comparing-estimated-actual-execution-plans-sql-server/ . It might be that due to stale statistics, the query planner has incorrect estimated row counts and is using the wrong operator

Comment: The two tables I am joining are static - once they were created, no data has changed within them, so the statistics should be up to date. For the sake of it, I have told SQL Server to update the table statistics, but this has no effect on the query plans.

Comment: Check the actual vs estimated and see if there are any discrepancies. Then you can rule that out. If it's using the wrong operator, this is where I would start looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem within SQL Server optimizer.

The condition `(t1.name1=t2.firstname and t1.name6=t2.lastname)` uses clustered index seek only and thus is very fast and executes almost instantly even with very large tables.

But the condition with OR

`(t1.name1=t2.firstname and t1.name6=t2.lastname) or (t1.name6=t2.firstname and t1.name1=t2.lastname)`

generally performs much worse usually performing full scan. You should see execution plans for your queries.

> The Query Optimizer will always perform a table scan or a clustered
>   index scan on a table if the WHERE clause in the query contains an OR
>   operator and if any of the referenced columns in the OR clause are not
>   indexed (or do not have a useful index). Because of this, if you use
>   many queries with OR clauses, you will want to ensure that each
>   referenced column in the WHERE clause has an index.
>
> If you have a query that uses ORs and it is not making the best use
>   of indexes, consider rewriting it as a UNION and then testing
>   performance. Only through testing can you be sure that one version of
>   your query will be faster than another.

[See here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22853/SQL-Server-Performance-Tips-and-Guidelines). So shortly your first OR query does not make good use of indexes.

I believe there is no other way than rewrite the query with UNION (as you did) or [APPLY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/72726/44324), optimizer will not do it.